# Action bar has disappeared

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and seem to be stuck at the moment. Whenever I compile and test my app on a device I getting a fatal error message:

```
=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4137d930)
12-10 22:07:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(20961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 22:07:28.423: E/AndroidRuntime(20961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hyperlocal.tradeit/com.hyperlocal.tradeit.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

then app stops running after the splash screen.

The action bar doesn't even appear in the graphical layout any more and the IDE cannot find any errors :/

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/2Fh9UVwf)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given the RelativeLayout an id of `android:id="@+id/pager"` and in your code, you are trying to access it thinking it's a ViewPager. These classes are **not** the same. In your RelativeLayout, you have to manually add a ViewPager and give that `android:id="@+id/pager`.

The [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) does a good job of providing a template.

Here is what your code should resemble.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
I apologise but I didn't entirely understand what you meant in your answer, I am very new to android app development.

In regards to your solution I copied and pasted the code you provided into my xml but could not see why it was not working, from what I can see in the MainActivity.java class i have coded
'mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);'
the xml states 'android:id="@+id/pager"' so aren't they both referencing the same id (pager) within the R.java file?

Comment: They are referencing the same id, what error are you having specifically? `@+id/pager` creates the id through the xml file and `R.id.pager` accesses it from the code.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you very much!

It turns out that the eclipse IDE I was using did not show the action bar and instead displayed a blank page but it works on my device.

Out of curiosity would it be possible to disable swiping between sections of the action bar and only allowing the user to click the buttons at the top to navigate?
Also how can I link each section to a different screen/xml?

Comment: Action bar is not the same as a ViewPager. With that being said, I haven't used ViewPager at all, so I am of little help, your main question was just straightforward. Best bet for you is to do some research, and if you haven't found anything, ask another question on stackoverflow.